# Error in partitionining SSD for RHEL 9.1 on MAC Mini 2010/12

Tags: linux, rhel, macintosh

Im trying to install RHEL 9.1 the ssd already had macOS and I messed it up, now I just want to install RHEL 9.1, partioning gives the following error.

Failed to find a suitable stage1 device: Apple EFI Boot Partition cannot be of type efi.; Apple EFI Boot Partition cannot be of type xfs.; Apple EFI Boot Partition must be mounted on one of /boot/efi.; Apple EFI Boot Partition cannot be of type xfs.; Apple EFI Boot Partition must be mounted on one of / boot/efi.; Apple EFI Boot Partition cannot be of type xfs.; Apple EFI Boot Partition must be mounted on one of /boot/efi.; Apple EFI Boot Partition cannot be of type xfs.; Apple EFI Boot Partition must be mounted on one of / boot/efi.; Apple EFI Boot Partition cannot be of type swap.

[image]